# Can I preserve a copy of an object, inside that object when its created

Tags: javascript, html, class, object

Can I preserve a copy of an object, inside that object when its created

This is my function which creates a new student object:

```
function student(id, name, marks){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.marks = marks;
}
```

I would like to create a copy of the object when it is initialized inside that object:
I came up with this:

```
function student(id, name, marks){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.marks = marks;
    this.baseCopy = this;
}
```

But the problem is its giving me a infinite loop of copies of current object in baseCopy; ANd also it is automatically updating when ever I update any attributes of my object.

**1. How is this possible such that, I can preserve a copy of an object with the initial values, inside that object when its created?**

Comment: can you give us an insight of the reason for this?... if you want changeTracking, rather implement one ... otherwise you could probably do a toJson/...-thing and save the value to a field

Comment: since you're using jQuery, look at `$.extend`

Comment: @JanDvorak funny - I wrote (almost) exactly that too :)

Comment: I'm receiving some data through JSON. and making student objects. The application runs mainly on clientSide. it updates only when the user want to commit the changes. So I need to log the changes that has been made

Comment: @AkhilSekharan then storing the initial state is actually not what you want unless you don't mind collapsing the changes (DB entity).

Comment: @JanDvorak. I need to save the changes to DB. and which are the fields changed. And its done on client side.

Comment: downvoted for _completely_ changing the question.

Comment: Or shall I post new question?

Comment: @AkhilSekharan might have been better.

Comment: @JanDvorak Okie, reverting back

Comment: @AkhilSekharan you can revert from the revision history. Are you reverting manually?

Comment: @JanDvorak reverted manually

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery the generic answer is:

```
this.baseCopy = $.extend(true, {}, this);
```

will produce a "deep" copy of any property values that exist at the time, without it recursively referring to itself.

**NOTE** - I did include some generic JS code, but then the OP completely changed the question, so it's simpler to revert back to just using jQuery.  This will of course copy any methods that exist directly on the object, although if written properly these methods would be on the object's prototype.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to have a solution without jQuery also?

Comment: @AkhilSekharan implement `$.extend` manually. Since you know the structure, it's trivial (`this.base.x = this.x = x`)

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes, Its possible. But curious to know if this is possible without hardcoding the attributes

Comment: removed my upvote for relying on ES5 (in a way that is impossible to shim "without the danger of a modified `Object.prototype`")

Comment: @JanDvorak you misunderstand - any decent shim for `Object.keys` would (correctly) use `hasOwnProperty()` to avoid enumerating properties added to the prototype.

Comment: @JanDvorak but you're the one that pointed out that adding to the prototype is necessary in shimming?!  That said, I didn't check whether any shims actually do change `Object.prototype` - obviously it's necessary that they change `Array.prototype`.

Comment: @Alnitak since you now allow extending `Object.prototype` for shimming, my upvote stays with you.

Comment: @JanDvorak since the OP just completely changed the question, I reverted back to just using `$.extend()` - sigh :(

Comment: @Alnitak he actually said it was a database entity in the comments, right? Who would have thought it was not a shallow object?

Comment: @JanDvorak IMHO a more normal mapping from DB to objects would use one object class per table, so each object would only contain its own data and _links_ to other objects containing their data.

Comment: @Alnitak actually, most often you want to map objects to database, not vice versa. Deep objects naturally map to multiple tables with foreign keys. Actually, a collection of objects is how JPA represents to-many relations and a single object is how it represents to-one relations.

Comment: @Alnitak anyways, the question is back, and with it, you can unrevert as well.

Answer (score 2):

A jQuery-less alternative:
(Just so you know it can also be done without.)

```
function student(id, name, marks){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.marks = marks;

    var tempCopy = {}; // Initialize a temporary variable to copy the student to.
    for(key in this){   // Loop through all properties on this (student)
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(key)){ // Object.prototype fallback. I personally prefer to keep it in, see Alnitak's comment.
            tempCopy[key] = this[key]; // Copy the property
        }
    }
    this.baseCopy = tempCopy; // "Save" the copy to `this.baseCopy`
}

var s = new student(1, 'Jack', [5,7]);
s.marks = s.marks.concat([6,8]); // Jack's gotten 2 new marks.

console.log(s.name + "'s marks were: ", s.baseCopy.marks);
console.log(s.name + "'s marks are: ", s.marks);
// Logs:
// Jack's marks were:  [5, 7]
// Jack's marks are:  [5, 7, 6, 8]
```

The advantage of this is that it will automatically copy *all* properties of the student, without having to "set" them in `baseCopy`, manually.
Also, since it doesn't use jQuery, it's a little faster. This could be significant when working with large amounts of data.

Comment: note that this will produce a shallow copy (this is OK for DB entities). This also means you _can_ copy the reference to the copy.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Ah, yes, should I add some recursion for objects?

Comment: note also that it would be far simpler to create a _local_ variable and fill that inside the loop, and _then_ assign that to `this.baseCopy`, hence avoiding the need to check for a recursive copy inside the loop.  Also `hasOwnProperty()` is kinda overkill these days.  People know better than to add to `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @Alnitak but they still extend other prototypes, like Array (for example when shimming).

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah, it's a shame that shimming to ES5 compatibility can't be done without adding enumerable properties.  I updated my answer to show how a browser could use ES5 methods (shimmed if necessary) safely even if `Object.prototype` has been modified.

Answer (score 1):

The following method works for me (might not be the best solution, there is probably another one which involves object prototypes)

```
function BaseStudent(id, name, marks) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.marks = marks;
}

function Student(id, name, marks) {
    this.baseCopy = new BaseStudent(id, name, marks);
    BaseStudent.call(this, id, name, marks);
}

var s = new Student(1, 'Name', 100);

console.log(s.id); // logs 1
console.log(s.name); // logs 'Name'
console.log(s.marks); // logs 100

s.name = 'AnotherName';

console.log(s.name); // logs 'AnotherName'
console.log(s.baseCopy.name);​ // logs 'Name'
```

Comment: or `BaseStudent.apply(this, arguments)`