# Can I preserve a copy of an object, inside that object when its created - Continued:

Tags: javascript, object

This is continuation of **[My Old Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968409/can-i-preserve-a-copy-of-an-object-inside-that-object-when-its-created)**

This is my function which creates a new student object:

```
function student(id, name, marks, mob, home){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.marks = marks;
    this.contacts = {};
    this.contacts.mob = mob;
    this.contacts.home = home;

    this.toContactDetailsString = function(){
        return this.name +':'+ this.mob +', '+ this.home
    }
}
```

I would like to create a copy of the object when it is initialized inside that object:
I came up with this:

```
function student(id, name, marks, mob, home){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.marks = marks;
    this.contacts = {};
    this.contacts.mob = mob;
    this.contacts.home = home;

    this.toContactDetailsString = function(){
        return this.name +':'+ this.mob +', '+ this.home
    }
    this.baseCopy = this; //Not sure about this part
}
```

But the problem is its giving me a infinite loop of copies of current object in baseCopy; ANd also it is automatically updating when ever I update any attributes of my object.

**1. How is this possible such that, I can preserve a copy of an object with the initial values, inside that object when its created?**

**2. Is it possible not to copy the functions**

**3. I'm very curious to know if this is possible without hard-coding attribute names and by using pure JS**

Comment: You don't assign a copy of the object to "baseCopy" there but a reference. No copying is done, that's why "baseCopy" is always "up to date". Take a look at, e.g., http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/ to get an idea how to get an actual copy.

Comment: `this` seems to be referring to the `window` object in this context.

Comment: So, did any of the answers posted work for you?

Comment: @Cerbrus: Thanks for wakin me up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much like my answer on your previous question, you can use this code to make a copy of the object and it's nested properties, while not copy-ing it's functions:

```
function student(id, name, marks, mob, home){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.marks = marks;
    this.contacts = {};
    this.contacts.mob = mob;
    this.contacts.home = home;

    this.toContactDetailsString = function(){
        return this.name +':'+ this.mob +', '+ this.home
    }

    // Copy the object to baseCopy 
    this.baseCopy = clone(this); // "clone" `this.baseCopy`
}

function clone(obj){
    if(obj == null || typeof(obj) != 'object'){ // If the current parameter is not a object (So has no properties), return it;
        return obj;
    }

    var temp = {};
    for(var key in obj){ // Loop through all properties on a object
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && !(obj[key]  instanceof Function)){ // Object.prototype fallback. Also, don't copy the property if it's a function.
            temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

var s = new student(1, 'Jack', [5,7], 1234567890, 0987654321);
s.marks = s.marks.concat([6,8]); // Jack's gotten 2 new marks.

console.log(s.name + "'s marks were: ", s.baseCopy.marks);
// Jack's marks were:  [5, 7]
console.log(s.name + "'s marks are: ", s.marks);
// Jack's marks are:  [5, 7, 6, 8]
console.log(s.baseCopy.toContactDetailsString); // check if the function was copied.
// undefined
console.log(s.baseCopy.contacts.mob);
// 1234567890
```

<strike>(I'll work on the deep copy for a sec)</strike>

The "deep" copy should work now.

Answer (score 3):

you are not creating a copy by saying

`this.baseCopy = this;` , you are just setting the reference to this inner variable. So baseCopy is also pointing to same object

You need to create a method which will return a new student object from passed student object and then store that as BaseCopy

Answer (score 1):

```
this.baseCopy = new student(id, name, marks);
```

Your way just makes a circular reference. Use `new` to instantiate a new object.

Using this will probably go into an infinite recursion though.

You can circumvent this like this:

```
function student(id, name, marks, flag) {
    // usual code...
    // And:
    if (!flag) {
        this.baseCopy = new student(id, name, marks, true);
    }
}
```

This way, only the top student has a baseCopy.

Comment: This probably won't work. When you new a copy with the same inputs.. the new copy will probably new another copy... which will new yet another copy.

Comment: this way.. baseCopy is still an instance of student, and should have the functions defined in it

Comment: Yep. Although it looks like OP doesn't want it, I still think it's the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Well...

```
this.baseCopy = this;
```

Basically means that the object's baseCopy is the object itself. So:

```
var abc = new student(someId, someName, someMarks);
```

abc and abc.baseCopy actually point to the same object.
What you can do is probably change baseCopy to:

```
this.baseCopy = { id: id, name: name, marks: marks, contact: {mob:mob, home: home}}
```

Basically manually create a copy of the inputs into an object.
Be aware that if any of the inputs are reference types, the copy will still point to the same object as the original.

Comment: You still need the methods.